# How to add Dyamic JSON Dropdown Menu in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, chart.js

Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/0eHQPVRHmCWelK6VEYVE?p=preview

This is an Analytics Chart from the JSON File: http://happyshappy.13llama.com/wp-json/llama/v1/stats

I want to put a dropdown menu on top of the chart, in the dropdown, the "label" element of the JSON should be visible via GET. 
Once the user selects a label, it's Data is visible in the Chart.

Please help me as soon as possible!

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://happyshappy.13llama.com/wp-json/llama/v1/stats').then(function(response) {
var visitDates = response.data.visits.labels.map(function(dateString) {
  return new Date(dateString);
});

$scope.visits = response.data.visits.datasets;
var dateData = [];
var countData = [], index = 0 , i;
angular.forEach($scope.visits, function(dataSet) {
  dataSet.data = dataSet.data.map(function(count, i) {
    index++;
    dateData[i] = visitDates[i];
    countData[i] = count;
    return {
      date: visitDates[i],
      count: count,
      dateData: dateData,
      countData: countData
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: http://happyshappy.13llama.com/wp-json/llama/v1/stats is not working, so we can't see the JSON

Comment: Fixed! Check again, and please suggest me a solution ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure at all about what do you want to do, but I thing that you want a select with the labels and if you click on a label then the chart displays the values of the label, right?

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in visits" ng-click="changeValues()" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

And then create the function in you controller

```
$scope.changeValues() {
    // You have the selected label in $scope.selected, so you have to iterate
    // over the visits array and then set the data where label == $scope.selected in the chart values
}
```

I can't test it right now but I hope that the idea helps you to solve the issue.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying. The first code is working, din't understand what to do with the second one. :(